# Why are c++ executables platform dependant?

Tags: c++, compilation, operating-system, cross-platform

I was looking to make a cross-platform software and by looking at how compiled C++ files (ie static or dynamic libraries or applications) are platform dependent, I was wondering what makes the binary platform dependent.

I know that the instruction set of the processor and using operating system specific c++ functions makes the binary/code platform dependent.

But let's assume that I have 2 x86 machines, one running linux, the other running windows and a C++ code. That code doesn't use any platform-specific functions. Why would my executable be operating dependant?

If it was just for os specific header in the application file, there would be converting tools elf<->exe but that's not the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: Totally different format, ABI

Comment: It's because of the architecture of portable executable files.

Comment: Program binaries not only have a different format on different OS (since it's the OS which loads them), but also depends on the OS system functions to work.

Comment: you should read this for an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: You just said "operating-specific functions make the binary platform-dependent". WIndows and Linux are different operating systems, so...?

Comment: Also check out [Wine](https://www.winehq.org).

Comment: It's for the same reason different cars require different parts.

Comment: Reading from the wiki page of the ABI, it makes sense that the binary has to be different from different Os especially considering system calls ty

Comment: @F.Jean: ABIs are only a comparatively minor part of this. Almost every aspect of the standard library (especially the bit imported from the C library) needs an OS specific implementation. For example, consider how you'd implement `std::exit`. That said, if you're able to provide an appropriate standard library, you can make some progress, which is how Wine works (and modern Windows 10 as far as I know, which can execute Linux binaries natively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An executable file contains a stream of instructions that instruct the loader how to place the program in memory. There are different formats for executable files used by different operating systems that reflect the different capabilities of operating systems.
2. Processors have different instruction sets as you mention.
3. Executable files load libraries that may be specific to one operating system.
4. Your executable may include stub code that invokes system services. System services are invoked by triggering exception handlers. The handling of exceptions will be different among operating system.
5. Operating systems have different calling conversions for functions. If you call the same function on different systems, you may have to call it in a different way.
6. The implementation of structures used by library calls can vary even when the name of the structure is the same.
7. The naming of functions can be different. The linkers on some operating system prefix, for example, an underscore to global and universal symbol names. Many do not.

I'll stop there but I am sure others could come up with more reasons.